# Join newest row off second table to each row of first table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have two tables:

```
Table 1
ID    Username
1     human
2     humane
3     humaner

Table 2
ID    userID  date        data1  data2
1     1       2017-10-25  25     12
2     1       2017-10-24  11     13
3     2       2017-10-25  43     24
```

And I want to join only the newest data of table 2 like this:

```
username  date         data1  data2
human     2017-10-25   25     12
humane    2017-10-25   43     24
```

How can I realize this in mysql with php?
I tried to do it with 2 connections but I think it's not really performant :)

Comment: Do you define *'newest data'* as dates after some specific date ? or the latest date in the table no matter when it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT  t1.*, t2.*
 FROM Table1 t1
 JOIN Table2 t2
   ON t1.ID = t2.user_id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM Table2 Q
                   WHERE Q.user_id = t2.user_id
                     AND Q.date > t2.date)
```